# Aspose converting Excel to HTML - htmlAgilePack

Tags: c#, excel, html-agility-pack, aspose

I am trying to convert an Excel file to an HTML file which I later display on the page as a preview. Everything works well except one element. I display the HTML file in the pop-up window and it does not fit in completely. How to make the generated HTML file match the width of the window? My point is that I do not have to scroll the page horizontally (only vertically like a classic scroll).

```
private void ConvertExcelToHtml(Stream stream, string fileName, string directory, string virtualDirectory, bool force)
{
    var htmlPath = Path.Combine(directory, $"{fileName}.html");
    if (force == false && System.IO.File.Exists(htmlPath))
    {
        return;
    }

    log.DebugFormat("Converting Excel=>HTML: '{0}'", fileName);
    var document = new Workbook(stream);
    this.RemoveHeader(document);

    var htmlSaveOptions = new Aspose.Cells.HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Html)
    {
        HiddenColDisplayType = HtmlHiddenColDisplayType.Remove,
        HiddenRowDisplayType = HtmlHiddenRowDisplayType.Remove,
        AttachedFilesDirectory = directory,
        ExportActiveWorksheetOnly = true,
    };

    htmlSaveOptions.ImageOptions.ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Png;
    document.Save(htmlPath, htmlSaveOptions);
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.Load(htmlPath);

    htmlDoc.Save(htmlPath);
}
```

Comment: I would kindly ask you to provide me a runnable sample code and template .xlsx, .html files you use, I will check your issue and try to help.

**Note**: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AlexandraGrazhevskaja below you can find generated HTML file. https://codeshare.io/UbKVU Unfortunately it is impossible to attach .xlsx in the StackOverflow. The problem lies in the fact that the generated HTML is displayed as a preview in a pop-up popup window that is smaller than the resolution of the screen and therefore does not fit properly.

Comment: Thank you for providing me the .html sample. I would kindly ask you to provide me more details: fully runnable sample, with the code of the popup, etc. You can zip the project and share it via dropbox or others. Thank you